# How can insert specific datetime into database from dateTimePicker C#

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, datepicker

i have  create a table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_dt(
> c_id NUMBER,
> c_dt DATE);
> ```
>
> than  change date format using the command :

```
> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS: AM';
```

and insert some value

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_dt(c_id,c_dt) values(06,TO_DATE('05/11/2017 9:22:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') );
> INSERT INTO table_dt(c_id,c_dt) values(07,TO_DATE('06/11/2017 4:02:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') );
> INSERT INTO table_dt(c_id,c_dt) values(08,TO_DATE('07/11/2017 3:30:00 PM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') );
> ```

this data is insert well  !

Now when i have try insert  data from  textBox1 & dateTimePicker1 i can not insert  it
i am using the code :

> ```
>  OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter("insert into
>  table_dt(c_id,c_dt) values('" + textBox1.Text + "',TO-DATE('" +
>  dateTimePicker1.Value.Date+"','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')", con);
>  adp.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
> ```

i have share my screen [image: pic]

Comment: Use parameters and a lot of problems will fade away

Comment: The NET OleDB provider is perfectly capable of accepting a DateTime type parameter without passing text and agonizing over formats.  Also read [ask] and take the [tour] - we need the error text not (small) pictures of error messages.

Comment: @SirRufo please give me example i am beginners for C#

Comment: @khan ask google. There are countless tutorials, samples and answered questions out in the web

Comment: There are THOUSANDS of examples here using parameters.  Get your google-fu on

Comment: If you don‘t know how to search, start with *c# oracle sql parameters*

Comment: @SirRufo,@Plutonix, thanks advice i will be try

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should use parameterized query instead of string concatenation. Your query is vulnerable to sql injection attack as it is. 
There is no such function "TO-DATE" in oracle, try "TO_DATE".